# Utilização de nome dinâmico para criação de arquivo

Tags: c++, string

Estou querendo criar arquivos com nomes dinâmicos para armazenamento de logs, porém, não tenho a mínima ideia de como conseguir o nome que desejo e também não sei como farei para formatar a string e usá-la com o "caminho/nome_arquivo.txt".

Meu código atual para escrita de arquivo:

```
//Inserir no arquivo de log
void appendKeyLog(Text key){
    ofstream logfile;
    logfile.open("sgdev_log.txt", ios::app);
    logfile << key;
    logfile.close();
```

O nome do arquivo o qual quero usar seria o `hostname` (o qual não sei como adquirir) em que o usuário se encontra (acredito ser o melhor nome para um identificador em meu projeto), tal nome substituiria o atual "sgdev_log.txt". E por fim, eu não sei como faria para montar e usar a string com `caminho_específico + nome_do_arquivo`.

Comment: Isso pode ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509532/how-to-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-with-c-sharp

Comment: Esse aí é para substituir dentro do arquivo

Comment: Eu sei. Você quer salva onde ou está seu arquivo?

Comment: eu quero salvar o nome do arquivo de forma dinâmica, independente do local escolhido, não o conteúdo.

Comment: Você quer que o usuário adicione o lugar?

Comment: não, preciso coletar o nome da máquina (hostname) e usá-lo para criar o arquivo com o mesmo nome do host

Comment: Consegui resolver, vou postar a resposta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após verificar que há um método para coletar o hostname (`getenv("COMPUTERNAME")`, este para `windows`), realizei alguns testes concatenando o retorno do `getenv` com a extensão do arquivo e funcionou, segue abaixo o código para criação de arquivo com nome dinâmico.

```
#include <string>

void appendKeyLog(Text key, string hostName){
    ofstream logfile;
    logfile.open((hostName + ".txt"), ios::app);
    logfile << key;
    logfile.close();
}
```